# Changing a field from a table depending on a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

The prototype software I am creating uses the MVC framework.

I am trying to change the `allowed` field in the `entrylog` table to either "Y" (Yes) or "N" (no) depending on whether a card associated with a driver is authorised or not.

The four tables involved are `card`, `driver`, `state` and the `entrylog` table. Also there is a `card_driver` table which associates a card with a driver.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `card` (
    `id`           int(11)     NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `startdate`    date        NOT NULL,
    `enddate`      date        NOT NULL,
    `state_id`     int(11)     NOT NULL,
    `referred_as`  varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `driver` (
    `id`           int(11)     NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `title`        varchar(40) default NULL,
    `supplier_id`  int(11)     NOT NULL,
    `referred_as`  varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `card_driver` (
    `card_id`      int(11)     NOT NULL,
    `driver_id`    int(11)     NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `state` (
    `id`           int(11)     NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `referred_as`  varchar(40) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `entrylog` (
    `id`           int(11)     NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `vehicle_id`   int(11)     NOT NULL,
    `driver_id`    int(11)     NOT NULL,
    `venue_id`     int(11)     NOT NULL,
    `supplier_id`  int(11)     NOT NULL,
    `deliverydate` date        NOT NULL,
    `allowed`      binary(1)   NOT NULL default 'N',
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

In the driver table I currently have code which checks the authorisation of a selected drivers associated card. I would like to apply this similiar code to the entry log, so that when using a form to enter a delivery it determines the 'allowed' field automatically. The code to check the drivers authorisation in the driver table is as follows:

```
if ($name == driver) {
?>
    <? include('common.php') ?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['check']))
{
$conn = mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
if(! $conn )
{
 die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$id = $_POST['id'];



$sql ="SELECT *
  FROM driver AS d 
INNER
  JOIN card_driver AS cd
    ON cd.driver_id = d.id
INNER
  JOIN card AS c
    ON c.id = cd.card_id     
 WHERE d.ID = $id";
mysql_select_db('damp');
$result = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
switch($row['state_id'])
{
case "1":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"green\">Authorisation Granted!</font></strong>";
   break;
case "2":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">Your card has expired and authorisation is denied</font></strong>";
   break;
case "3":
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">Your card has been cancelled and authorisation is denied</font></strong>";
   break;
default:
   echo "<strong><font color=\"red\">The Card ID does not exist</font></strong>";
}
```

Thank you for any help or advise you can give me.

**EDIT : Code from controller_create.php**

```
  if ($class_obj == "entrylog")
  {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $driverid = MyActiveRecord::FindById('driver',$this_obj->driver_id);
    $query = mysql_query("SUPDATE entrylog el
INNER JOIN driver AS d ON d.driver_id = el.driver_id 
INNER JOIN card_driver AS cd ON cd.driver_id = d.id
INNER JOIN card AS c ON c.id = cd.card_id     
SET el.allowed = CASE WHEN c.state_id = 1 
                      THEN 'Y' 
                      ELSE 'N' 
                 END
WHERE el.ID = $entryLogId");

mysql_select_db('damp');
  }
```

Comment: I don't see the question, error codes, or what you are stuck with.

Comment: The question is how do i change the allowed field in the entry log to either Y or N depending on the sql query which i have shown? The query currently works by taking a driver id from the driver table and chekcing the status of their associated card. I need the query to work so that it takes a drivers id from the entry log table and then performs the same query as above. But, if the authorisation is granted the allowed field in the entry log changes to Y. If authorisation is not granted the field is changed to N for No. Thanks.;

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to put an UPDATE query inside of `case "1"`. If so, take a stab at it and update here if you run into trouble.

Comment: Presumably then all `entrylog` records for the `driver_id` `$id` will be updated to the same value? or are you going to specify the `entrylog.id` to update? If `entrylog` is genuinely a log, it seems unlikely that you should want to go back through updating it, since presumably you want the `allowed` value at the time of logging.

Comment: The entrylog id would be specified. The entrylog is just another table which records a drivers attempt to access a venue. An entry will be made manually by the user by clicking on a form. (This system is only a prototype)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear on what you're asking but the following may help:

```sql
UPDATE entrylog el
INNER JOIN driver AS d ON d.id = el.driver_id 
INNER JOIN card_driver AS cd ON cd.driver_id = d.id
INNER JOIN card AS c ON c.id = cd.card_id     
SET el.allowed = CASE WHEN c.state_id = 1 
                      THEN 'Y' 
                      ELSE 'N' 
                 END
WHERE el.ID = $entryLogId
```

From your most recent comment it sounds like this value should be calculated as part of your `INSERT` though, rather than an `UPDATE` later.

Comment: I added thsi into the controller_create.php . When a new exntry is created , it submits , shows an error and then refreshes to shopw the data I have just enterd. It does not set the allowed field.   I have posted an edit with the code i now have in the controller_create.php .

Comment: It says SUPDATE instead of UPDATE, and you need to define $entryLogID

Comment: Presumably you have an INSERT when the driver records delivery? If so it would be better to show that INSERT so I can adapt it.

Comment: Whoops! What do you mean by define?

Comment: At the moment you get the ID of the driver, but you need to get the ID of the entrylog record you want to update. Using the driver's ID you'd end up changing the allowed value for every delivery the driver has ever made. Alternatively (and ideally) you should set the value during the INSERT instead.

Comment: the entrylog id is an auto increment value that I dont set when creating a new entry log

Comment: I know that but there are way of getting that ID, still I'm 99% sure this is all going to be done in your INSERT

Comment: Do you mean the insert when you create a new entry?

Comment: Not as such . Basicly I was given this MVC system to work on . The create controller automaicly genrates a form and therfore an insert statment based on the current page being viewed. There may be one deep in teh code , but I have yet to find it . Also I tried changing the WHERE el.id part to this WHERE el.ID = '1'" asuming that It would change the value of the first entry , but it didnt and left it blank .

Comment: Sorry when i chnaged it to 1 , it did actualy change the allowed for that entry . Could i do something like this :P $entryLogId = $data['Auto_increment'];  ?

Comment: I was referenceing `d.driver_id` instead of `d.id`, fixed. [Works fine here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6c526/1), I don't think the binary datatype is what you are looking for so I changed it to char. So if that works, you just need to locate the correct entrylog record to update. Can you not just use something like `MyActiveRecord::FindById('entrylog',$this_obj->id);`

Comment: Im getting somewher now . I didt this :$entryLogId = MyActiveRecord::FindById('entrylog',$this_obj->id); but i got this erro when i submited the form : Catchable fatal error: Object of class entrylog could not be converted to string . It still put in the record but didnt chnage the allowed field.

Comment: Thank you very much , turns out I had a last_inserted_record variable already defined and it works . Long Live Hypnotoad !

Comment: Ah nice one, no problem. All glory to the hypnotoad